# Is it possible to register an API Gateway in CloudMap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Ive been working with cloudmap recently for ECS and have a private namespace configured. I'd like to register my Lambda API Gateways within the same Route53/Cloudmap so that they can be queried with a fixed & sensible DNS entry internally e.g. myservice.local. I've been reading a bunch of articles and have yet to come across an easy to follow example. Reading this cloudmap article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud-map/latest/api/Welcome.html the bottom suggests it is possible to register an API gateway in cloudmap, but when I try to register a service in the console it requires an IP address, which I don't have because Lambda.

Is this actually possible, or some variation of this possible? I'd like to have all my lambdas running privately but I'm open to running them public and locking them down in other ways.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do that using the DNS-based discovery, but it sounds like you could use the API-based discovery for API Gateway URLs, as referenced by https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloud-map-easily-create-and-maintain-custom-maps-of-your-applications/ .